# URL Protocol for mspaint passes wrong paramaters

Tags: registry, protocols, url-scheme

I am trying to create a URL Protocol for opening a file in ms paint.

I set up the registry keys, and added this button to my page:

```
<a href="mspaint:C:\Users\Bassie\Pictures\hqdefault.jpg">Open in Paint</a>
```

But when I click the link, this error appears in a pop-up from paint:

```
---------------------------
Paint
---------------------------
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\mspaint:C:\Users\Bassie\Pictures\hqdefault.jpg contains an invalid path.
```

I know the cli should work, as manually entering into the command prompt opens the file as expected

```
$ mspaint C:\..my\..path
```

My registry looks like this:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL: mspaint Protocol"
"DefaultIcon"="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe, 1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure why it passes the parameter like that, but I ended up just writing my own protocol handler:

```
namespace ProtocolHandler
{
    class Program
    {
        const string NOARGSMESSAGE = "No args received";

        const string MESSAGEBOXCAPTION = "Paint Protocol Handler";
        const string APPLICATIONPATH = "mspaint";
        const string URLPROTOCOL = "mspaint:";
        const string ERRORMESSAGE = "An error occured when trying to open the file";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (args.Length < 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(NOARGSMESSAGE, MESSAGEBOXCAPTION);
                }
                else
                {
                    var filePath = GetFilePath(args);
                    Process.Start(APPLICATIONPATH, filePath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(MESSAGEBOXCAPTION, $"{ERRORMESSAGE} \n {e.Message}", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private static string GetFilePath(string[] args)
        {
            return args[0].Replace(URLPROTOCOL, string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And added these keys to the registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint]
@="Url:Paint Protocol Handler"
"URL Protocol"=""
"UseOriginalUrlEncoding"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Path\\To\\Paint Protocol Handler.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mspaint\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\Path\\To\\Paint Protocol Handler.exe %1"
```

The `DefaultIcon` key never seems to work though